# Polymer 1.x insert image with paper-input

Tags: html, css, image, css-selectors, polymer

Here is my situation - whenever there is a paper-input-error, I want to display an image with the error messafe. So I want to generate code such that it looks like

```
<paper-input-error ng-if="isError">{{errorMessage}}
    <iron-icon icon="icons:warning"</iron-icon>
</paper-input-error>
```

I was trying to add code using css using the ::after tag

```
<style>
   paper-input-error::before{
     content:'<iron-icon icon="icons:warning"</iron-icon>';   
   }
<style>
```

But that doesn't work. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

```
// import paper-input-error
<dom-module id="element-name">

      <template>
        <style>
          /* CSS rules for your element */
        </style>

        <!-- local DOM for your element -->

        <paper-input-error ng-if="isError">{{errorMessage}}
           <iron-icon icon="icons:warning"</iron-icon>
        </paper-input-error>
      </template>

      <script>
        // element registration
        Polymer({
          is: "my-input-error",

          // add properties and methods on the element's prototype

          properties: {
            // declare properties for the element's public API
            isError: {
              type: Boolean,
              value: false
            },
            errorMessage: {
              type: String,
              value: 'Error!'
            }
          }
        });
      </script>

    </dom-module>
```

Comment: So what would be a way of adding html each time after a particular element?

Comment: But how would an image be automatically added whenever I use paper-input-error? I don't want to change my code to add the <iron-icon icon="icons:warning"</iron-icon> tag after ever paper-input-error in my project.

Comment: See above - I need this code to be automatically generated

Comment: Oh, so you want to extend paper-input-error, see the update

Comment: Great! Thank you. I was hoping not to create a custom element, but that is a clean solution